# HTTP Server with Redis Event Loop

Tags: c, events, redis

I'm a newbie, and I was trying to test the code [here](https://github.com/aisk/libae/blob/master/example/echo.c) (which uses Redis event loop)

But when i make a request to 127.0.0.1:8000, the server doesn't send the response, it hangs. Do i need to make some changes ? I just need the request to be echoed back, which the example intends to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think this thing is a HTTP server? It is not. It is a broken TCP echo server.

It is broken, because the write operation is not under the control of the event loop. Some bytes will be lost if the non blocking write operation cannot send all the bytes (you have no such guarantee).

Now, if you use a proper client, this program can still be demonstrated:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
toto
toto
titi
titi
tutu
tutu

... while the output of the program itself is:

Accepted 127.0.0.1:48645
```

If you want to play with event loops, I would suggest picking one among the following list. They are probably much better documented than the first random ae hack found on github ...

- [libevent](http://libevent.org/)
- [libev](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod)
- [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv)